# Magmi a huge amount of categories in one product

Tags: magento, magmi

In my CSV for Magmi, each product is set to 50 or more categories.

The value of CSV column `"categories"` look like this:

```
"Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 365 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 365 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 373 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 375 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 377 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 383 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 385 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 387 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 395 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 145 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 6690 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 585 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCPJ/DCPJ 715 W,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 163 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 165 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 167 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 185 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 195 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 197 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 5490 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 5890 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 5895 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 255 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 250 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 290 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 295 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 297 C,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 6490 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 990 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 6690 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 6890 CDW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 6890 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFCJ/MFCJ 615 W,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 795 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 490 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 790 CW,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 160 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 190 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 370 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 380 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 250 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 290 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 490 CN,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 490 Series,Cartridge Brother/Brother MFC/MFC 790 Series";
```

With this, I have a problem during import at MAGMI "**On the fly category creator**":

```
SQL Error: 1406 Data too long for column 'value' at row X (table catalog_category_entity_varchar)
```

There is column named "value" in `varchar(255)`. When I change this format to `text(2000)`, it will start to make Magento faults in another part, it seems to be never-ending story and a bad solution.

i found that each of the category path is not so long. It have standard lenght about 100 characters. But Magmi tries to save all categories to the MySQL to "value" column field. Why? can I change this? For each row in the table should be saved only one category path like "Cartridge Brother/Brother DCP/DCP 190 Series"

How can i prevent saving all the categories to one row at Magento table `catalog_category_entity_varchar` ?

Any better solution to import that bunch on categories with product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i used old category brunch separator ",", in my version of On the fly category creator should be ";;".